# Submitted to too many Perforce Jobs

Tags: perforce

I'm trying to submit to perforce but I'm getting the error message:

> Submit validation failed -- fix problems then use 'p4 submit -c 755024'.
>   'Max number of jobs' validation failed: You have attached more than 20 jobs to this >changelist. If you would like to attach that many jobs please contact perforcehelp.
>   Otherwise please bring the number of attached jobs to 20 or below and resubmit.

Normally when I submit, I get a text file that I can edit to lower the number of jobs I can submit to. This is no longer popping up. How do I change which jobs I'm submitting to?

Comment: Fixed, just do p4 change #changelist where #changelist is the changelist number (in my case 755024).

Comment: For reference, the error is due to a trigger which your Perforce admins have configured.